# lengthy criteria in dataframe selector

Tags: pandas

I'd like to get records with country codes not in a long list , something along the lines of

```
country_list = ['BR','MX','CO',...]
df = df[df['country_code'] not in country_list]

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

what's an elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df[~df['country_code'].isin(country_list)]
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator